# Computer dims immediately when remove power cord

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have an Asus Windows 8 computer. Very strange, whenever I remove the power cord, the screen dims immediately. And very dim. The battery lasts for five hours -- but not much use if the screen is so dim!

I checked the power settings. It doesn't show such a setting that immediately it should dim. Maybe after 10 minutes!

I changed the setting to 20 minutes, but no change.....

Comment: I think your laptop lcd inverter may be on its way out... The display settings won't take the screen _really_ dim (almost to the point you can't see anything). If you can barely see anything then there is a hardware fault; mostly the inverter.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand my problem:

**My problem:** I had tried using function keys to change the screen brightness -- but without success. So then I had tried changing the power settings for the computer. I set that when the computer is on battery -- it should only dim after 10 minutes. **But the computer would still dim immediately when beginning battery power!**

**My solution:** I misunderstood my function keys. I was using keys **which change the brightness of lights which are under the keys of my keyboard.** So now that I found the right function keys, I can adjust the brightness of the screen.

Those function keys also change the setting of screen brightness in my current power plan.

I guess the setting of dim after 10 minutes in the power plans is some other additional dimming of the screen.

THANK YOU for all who responded!

Avrohom